# Fancyheader footer for float pages

Tags: floats, fancyhdr

I'm trying to keep the page number on float pages using `fancyhdr`. Here is my current set-up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\iffloatpage{}{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\iffloatpage{}{\textbf\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\iffloatpage{}{\textbf\leftmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headsep}{10pt}
\iffloatpage{\cfoot{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}{}
\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip} % make space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{demo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately the line that I thought would do what I wanted (`\iffloatpage{\cfoot{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}{}`) is doing nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it the other way round:

```
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}{}}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% with this we ensure that the chapter and section
% headings are in lowercase.
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\iffloatpage{}{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\fancyhf{} % delete current setting for header and footer
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\iffloatpage{}{\textbf\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\iffloatpage{}{\textbf\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\iffloatpage{\textbf{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{0.5pt}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headsep}{10pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip} % make space for the rule
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{} % get rid of headers on plain pages
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % and the line
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{demo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added the `twoside` class option; otherwise, `E` and `O` have no use.