# Removing headers and footers from two consecutive pages

Tags: header-footer

\thispagestyle{empty} works for removing the first page I wish to remove headers and footers. But I put this command again hoping that it would work for the next page, but it doesn't seem to. I only want these two pages to be without header and footers as I have figures on these.

Cheers!

Comment: Possibly related, the other way around, but maybe can be adapted: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167637/fancyheader-footer-for-float-pages Also look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13307/how-to-remove-header-on-the-page-with-big-picture-or-a-page-containing-floats

Comment: you give very little information, but is there any reason you can not use `\pagestyle{empty}` before the pages and `\pagestyle{plain}% or whatever it was` after them?

Comment: Or just put `\thispagestyle{empty}` somewhere in the middle of the content of the next page? That is, it will always apply to *this* page, so wait till the next page is this one.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \pagestyle{empty} followed by \pagestyle{fancy} worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @cfr I think that may have been why \thispagestyle{empty} was not working for me as the pages are just figures, so perhaps it wasn't picking up on the content?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\pagestyle{empty}` before the pages and `\pagestyle{fancy}` after them.